# Reliably identifying any window's client area

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a program that will replicate, and then extend the functionality of Aero Snap.

Aero Snap restores a maximized window, if the user "grabs" it's title bar, and I am having difficulties identifying this action.

Given a cursor position in screen coordinates, how would I check if the position is within the window's title bar? I am not really at home in the Win32 API, and could not find a way that works reliably for complicated scenarios such as:

[image: example for a difficult title bar]

Note that tabs that chrome inserts into the title bar. Office does something similar with the quick launch menu.

Comment: [`WM_NCHITTEST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618(v=vs.85).aspx) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Both Chrome and Office make use of the `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` function. This really complicates things, since this effectively makes part of the window that _is rendered_ as part of the Non-Client area actually belong to the client area. In these instances, you simply cannot tell where the title-bar ends and the client area begins. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx I reckon, your best bet might be to explicitly send WM_NCHITTEST messages to the application. Since it should return HTCAPTION (provided it also self-handles WM_NCHITTEST)

Comment: Nice, I think this is what I was looking for. This works nicely for Chrome, but Excel always reports "client area" anywhere. I guess that's Excel's fault, though =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

title bar hits are via the message "non client" messages - ie the area of a window that is not the client (or inner) window.

[WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms645620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is probably the message you want to trap.

You also probably want to set a [window hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to hook mouse messages, if its the NC message you want, you handle it your way, if not - pass it on to the message chain.

Edit: if Chrome is using the DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea calls to draw the tabs, then you will need to use WM_NCHITTEST.

Comment: Thanks! I'll maybe try this approach later (since I am really working with C# and global hooks seem to be.. difficult).